# Best PHP code style checker with Checkstyle-compatible output format

Tags: php, continuous-integration, teamcity, code-standards

I am configuring CI server and want to add code style check step to build steps sequence. My CI server is TeamCity such code style check step must produce XML output compatible with [codestyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) format. I have found few tools for PHP code style check and I confused which one should I use.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out [PHPCheckstyle](https://github.com/PHPCheckstyle/phpcheckstyle)? It has an option for outputting to the checkstyle format.

Comment: Thank you! Fortunately this task already not in my authority.